# Are the _Thrd_create() and other thread functions of Visual Studio C implementations of Thrd_ C11 functions?

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 has little to no C99 and C11 language support however in some areas it seems to have underlying primitives that are similar but with a modified version of the primitve name.

Specifically I am looking at the support of the multi-thread library of C11.

It appears, when looking in the include file `thr/xthreads.h` that most of the C11 multi-threading library primitives are available however the names of the functions are prefixed by an underscore. In other words `thrd_create()` is `_Thrd_create()` and the include file `threads.h` does not exist but `thr/xthreads.h` does.

Reading this blog post from Herb Sutter dated 2012/05/03, [Reader Q&A: What about VC++ and C99?](https://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/), it appears that Microsoft had few plans to implement C99 nor C11 in Visual Studio though other bits and pieces of commentary and questions on the internet indicate that position may have changed since 2012.

How likely is there to be continued support for the multi-threading library declared in the include file `thr/xthreads.h`?

What assurances do I have that these primitives will be maintained in Visual Studio 2019 and later? Is there any other information available as to Microsoft plans for Visual Studio?

I put together the following simple example in a .c extension source file after created a Windows console application in Visual Studio 2017. The `main()` is in a .cpp source file and is composed of a call to the `func()` function below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thr/xthreads.h>    //  access the underlying C11 threads library.

typedef struct {
    int ik;
    int ij;
    _Thrd_t *p;
} Thing;

int tx1 ( void * y)
{
    Thing * x = (Thing *)y;
    xtime xTimeAmt = {0};


    printf("One this is thread %d  %d\n", x->ik, x->ij);

    _Thrd_yield();

    xtime_get(&xTimeAmt, TIME_UTC);

    xTimeAmt.sec += 5;         // wait 5 seconds
    _Thrd_sleep(&xTimeAmt);

    printf("Two this is thread %d  %d\n", x->ik, x->ij);

    return 0;
}

_Thrd_t tt1;
_Thrd_t tt2;
_Thrd_t tt3;

int func(void)
{
    Thing t1 = { 1, 10 };
    Thing t2 = { 2, 20 };
    Thing t3 = { 3, 30 };
    int   rt1, rt2, rt3;

    for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
    }

    _Thrd_create((t1.p = &tt1), tx1, &t1);
    _Thrd_create((t2.p = &tt2), tx1, &t2);
    _Thrd_create((t3.p = &tt3), tx1, &t3);

    _Thrd_join(tt1, &rt1);
    _Thrd_join(tt2, &rt2);
    _Thrd_join(tt3, &rt3);

    for (int i = 23; i < 30; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
i = 8
i = 9
One this is thread 1  10
One this is thread 2  20
One this is thread 3  30
Two this is thread 1  10
Two this is thread 3  30
Two this is thread 2  20
i = 23
i = 24
i = 25
i = 26
i = 27
i = 28
i = 29
```

Comment: You should probably be using the functions described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multiple-threads) for threads on Windows, or a pthreads wrapper

Comment: @Shawn my hope is that I could write my own C11 style wrappers using these Visual Studio 2015 thread functions which looks to be either a one line in-line function definition or using #define with the Preprocessor. I would like to maintain the same interface and same style of function library.

Comment: @RichardChambers: +1 if for no other reason than that that's a great motivation for the question!

Answer (score 2):

> How likely is there to be continued support for the multi-threading library declared in the include file thr/xthreads.h?

Unlikely.

> What assurances do I have that these primitives will be maintained in Visual Studio 2019 and later?

None.

> Is there any other information available as to Microsoft plans for Visual Studio?

Well, as [the standard states](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.1):

> Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.)

You should never rely on any of their behavior. To quote [a relevant MS bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/413586/-thrd-create-is-missing-from-xthreadsh.html):

> Like all underscore-capital _Ugly machinery, such bits may be added, changed, and removed in any update (unless the machinery is a specifically documented exception, like _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL, or basic_string::_Copy_s).

And they also state what you *should* do instead:

> You should call documented APIs, like `std::thread` or `_beginthreadex`, instead.